# Error Number: 1054

Tags: error

Just moved my current EE 2.9.2 website to another host and I am getting the following error on the admin.php and the index.php.

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column ‘sess_start’ in ‘field list’

INSERT INTO `exp_sessions` (`admin_sess`, `session_id`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `member_id`, `last_activity`, `sess_start`, `fingerprint`) VALUES (1, ‘2050e961294359515d6732a160850dcb2491a826’, ‘81.xxx.xxx.xxx’, ‘Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36’, 1, 1435579185, 1435579185, ‘b89d80a5323e17c04cc0bfec10a1b2fa’)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 409
```

Any ideas how this could be resolved?

Comment: Well did you investigate that database table and column to see if it exists?

Comment: @jchrono-battle I just checked. I don't seem to have 'sess_start' as a field. Shall I just create one?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your database migration failed somehow. With conditions like that, I usually re-attempt the data migration. Yes, you can just create that column, but you might run into other malformed migrated tables. Make sure you look at your original database server, and that you create a column with identical properties to the original that didn't get created on migration. Let me know what happens.